# How to get two Foundation menus next to each other?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I can't sort out the right tricks with the Foundation class, to have my two menus (the two `<ul>` structures) to be next to each other on the same line.

[image]

Here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/pnoeric/pen/yvgOOv/

```
<div class="top-bar" id="responsive-menu">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <a class="title-bar-title" href="#">
            Site Title Goes Here
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class='menu align-right'>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class='menu align-right'>
            <li>Menu 2 One</li>
            <li>Menu 2 Two</li>
            <li>Menu 2 Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ul` is block level, by default it takes the entire row available, and two `ul` elements means two rows. There are many ways to change that such as:

```
.top-bar-right {
  display: flex;
}
```

or

```
.top-bar-right ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and looks like the framework set the `li` to float, otherwise that needs to be reset to.